# How to get solution results while running the main?

Tags: cplex

How to get models solutions in problem browser and in solutions window while running the main if I have a main or if I run two models from the main i only have scripting log data that I wrote in   writeln(); in the script of the main, but i want to appear every input, decision variable, constrains and the results in the problem browser as appearing in running the model without main

Comment: @ Alex Fleischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a model with a main part (flow control) in the CPLEX IDE you see the result from the last solve in the problem browser.

For instance if you run https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooincremental.mod in the IDE

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ emptyVar;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
 
 ctEmpty:0<=0;

}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
writeln("The minimum cost is ",costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30);
writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses and ",nbBus30," 30 seats buses ");
writeln();
}

main
{
thisOplModel.generate();

writeln("Basic model");

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

writeln("Let us add a row : saying that nbBus40 and nbBus30 should be equal");

thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus40,1);
thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus30,-1);
thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setBounds(0,0);
cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

writeln("Let us add a column : saying that nbBus50 could also be used and their cost is 700");
cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.emptyVar,700);
thisOplModel.ctKids.setCoef(thisOplModel.emptyVar,50);
cplex.solve();
writeln("The minimum cost is ",
thisOplModel.costBus40*thisOplModel.nbBus40.solutionValue  +thisOplModel.nbBus30.solutionValue*thisOplModel.costBus30
+700*thisOplModel.emptyVar.solutionValue);
writeln("We will use ",thisOplModel.nbBus40.solutionValue," 40 seats buses ",thisOplModel.nbBus30.solutionValue,
" 30 seats buses and "+thisOplModel.emptyVar.solutionValue," 50 seats buses");
}
```

you will see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

This is my main model
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRfuy.png